# Convert NSDictionary into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, nsdictionary

I'm trying to put NSDictionary data into a table view. But I'm having problem accesing values.

The dictionary looks like this:

```
multimedia =     {
        uploads =         {
            upload =             (
                                {
                    FileName =                     {
                        text = "\n      1-FB5A9792.MOV";
                    };
                    status =                     {
                        text = "\n      2";
                    };
                    Event =                     {
                        text = "\n      Test";
                    };
                    Date =                     {
                        text = "\n      9/7/2016 9:06:21 AM";
                    };
                    Publicacion =                     {
                        text = "\n      Example";
                    };
                    Seccion =                     {
                        text = "\n      Sistemas";
                    };
                    id =                     {
                        text = "\n  \n    \n      993";
                    };
                    text = "\n    ";
                },
                                {
                    FileName =                     {
                        text = "\n      2-FB5A9793.MOV";
                    };
                    status =                     {
                        text = "\n      2";
                    };
                    Event =                     {
                        text = "\n      Test";
                    };
                    Date =                     {
                        text = "\n      9/7/2016 9:06:21 AM";
                    };
                    Publicacion =                     {
                        text = "\n      Example";
                    };
                    Seccion =                     {
                        text = "\n      Sistemas";
                    };
                    id =                     {
                        text = "\n    \n      994";
                    };
                    text = "\n    ";
                },
                                {
                    FileName =                     {
                        text = "\n      1-IMG_0006.MOV";
                    };
                    status =                     {
                        text = "\n      2";
                    };
                    Event =                     {
                        text = "\n      Highest";
                    };
                    Date =                     {
                        text = "\n      9/7/2016 4:56:37 PM";
                    };
                    Publicacion =                     {
                        text = "\n      Example";
                    };
                    Seccion =                     {
                        text = "\n      Sistemas";
                    };
                    id =                     {
                        text = "\n    \n      995";
                    };
                    text = "\n    ";
                },...
```

I´m using XMLReader to convert an XML to Dictionary, then pass the above data to tableData

```
 tableData = [jsonDictionary allKeys];
```

Table

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}
```

Creating cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    NSString *key = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:key];
    // get values from the dictionary and set the values for the displayed cell ...

    return cell;
}
```

I´m trying to put a cell for each FileName and status values, in this case 3 cells for each FileName.
But I'm not sure how to do that or get the count of FileName's.

This is the XML

```
<multimedia>
  <uploads>
    <upload>
      <id>1136</id>
      <Date>9/9/2016 11:01:58 AM</Date>
      <FileName>IMG_0510.MOV</FileName>
      <status>2</status>
      <Publicacion>Example</Publicacion>
      <Seccion>Sistemas</Seccion>
      <Event>Q</Event>
    </upload>
  </uploads>
</multimedia>
```

Comment: Is that the `jsonDictionary`'s output? or show what value is `jsonDictionary` assigned to.

Comment: Yep, is the jsonDictionary log, `NSLog(@"%@", jsonDictionary);`

Comment: whats the ouput of `jsonDictionary.count`

Comment: `jsonDictionary` = 1, `jsonDictionary[@"multimedia"]` = 2 and  `jsonDictionary[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"]` = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get data like this: `NSMutableArray *tableData = dict[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"];`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    NSDictionary *upload = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // get values from the dictionary and set the values for the displayed cell ...

    NSString *event = upload[@"Event"][@"text"];
    event = [event stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    cell.labelEvent.text = event;

    NSString *date = upload[@"Date"][@"text"];
    date = [date stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    cell.labelDate.text  = date;  

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `upload` prints from `FileName =     {...` until `text = "\n    ";` in each, but `upload[@"Event"][@"text"];` prints nothing, the labels are empty :(

Comment: Thanks Mr. UB, I changed 
`[dictInProgress setObject:textInProgress forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];` by 
`[dictInProgress setObject:[textInProgress stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];` in XMLReader.m and data is displayed

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that count should be 1.

Original jsonDictionary has only one item. You should go deeper to the upload and then call count.

Key `@"upload"` holds array inside. So, `jsonDictionary[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"]` should return an `array`. If you cast it into `NSDictionary` it will return wrong results, and you will get wrong results if you will try to get value for key `File name`.

The main purpose of dictionaries are that you have only one value for specific key. This is why you only get one `File name`, if you cast array into `NSDictionary`.

So :

```
NSArray * array = _xmlDictionary[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"];
NSDictionary * onUpload = array[i];
NSDictionary * fileName = array[i][@"FileName"];
NSString * fileNameString = array[i][@"FileName"][@"text"];
```

So in your case :

```
tableData = jsonDictionary[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"];
```

and then

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    NSDictionary *upload = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *fileName = upload[@"FileName"][@"text"];
    NSString *status = upload[@"status"][@"text"];
    NSString *event = upload[@"event"][@"text"];
    ...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `NSDictionary *subDictionary = jsonDictionary[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"]; `
`NSUInteger keyCount = [subDictionary count]; // returns 8` having just one `FileName`, don't know why

Comment: `tableData[0][@"FileName"];` crashes when I only have 1 `FileName` when there are more than one it gives the value, but placing the code as the label text inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` crashes and logs `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: Please provide me an xml that you are parsing and library that you are parsing with.

Comment: Sure, i update the question, i tested using it as printed on the question and adding more `<upload>` 's to `<uploads>` I parse the xml with [XMLReader](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/)

Comment: I tested code... and update my answer,... link to the XMLReader leads to old version without using ARC

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your JSON in a local JSON file and parsed that to display the result.

So you can follow the code after getting the dictionary,

So the line you should start from this line
   `NSArray *json = jsonTemp[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"];`

`jsonTemp` containing all data of your dictionary.
Here in the code i am showing only File name, you can use other key to display the other data accordingly.

**Here is My Code :**

```
- (void)loadJsonData
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSDictionary *jsonTemp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

    NSArray *json = jsonTemp[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"];

    for (NSDictionary *dictTemp in json) {
        [arrEvents addObject:dictTemp];
    }

    [tblView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - TableView Delegate -
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrEvents count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 49;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ListingIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *dictTemp = [arrEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *fileName = dictTemp[@"FileName"][@"text"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"File Name : %@", fileName];

    cell.backgroundColor = CLEAR_COLOR;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Output :
[image]

Hope it helps

Happy coding ...